# Why is there an $x$ when solving the derivative of $\theta_1$ and not $\theta_0$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, machine-learning

[image: img]
I understand how he found the first derivative but why is there an $x$ superscript (i) in the second but not in the first? I circled it in the image. The original formula is above.
Thanks!

Comment: Applying the chain rule: first derivative is taken from exponent $2$ (it comes down), then from inside brackets w.r.t. $\theta_1$, therefore its coefficient $x^1$ is multiplied

Comment: Thanks! That answered my question

Comment: Please [use mathjax next time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1} J(\theta_0,\theta_1) 
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1} \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m (\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)})^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1} (\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)})^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m 2(\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1} (\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) \;\;\;\,\text{ Via Chain rule} \\ &= \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m 2(\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1} ( \theta_1x^{(i)})\\
&= \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m 2(\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) x^{(i)} \underbrace{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_1} ( \theta_1)  }_1 \\
&= \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (\theta_0 + \theta_1x^{(i)} - y^{(i)}) x^{(i)}
\end{align}